# Obtains detail agent JSON of an agent selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application that consists of 2 controllers in one of them I get a list of agents and in the other I get the description of that agent, when an img icon is clicked the first agent shows it without problems but when you want to get the second it does not show anything.

Any point of view is appreciated

I have followed the promise pattern but I do not know if this is affecting the return of the second object

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

  var app=  angular.module('app',['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','agentsSrv']);
    
   app.controller("agentsCtrl",['$scope','agentsService','agentDetailService' ,function ($scope,agentsService,agentDetailService) {
      
  //Obtains the id of Agente and inyect to url
      $scope.info = function getId (agent){
       var url = "http://localhost:9080/DAPortfolioServices-war/portfolio/v1/assign/"+agent;
       agentDetailService.getId(url);
       alert(url);
      }
    var promise = agentsService.getAgents();
       
       promise.then(function(data)
        { 
       $scope.pageNumber = 1;//Pagina Actual
       $scope.items = [10,20,30]; // Valores de Paginacion
       $scope.selectPage=10; // Valor por defecto de paginacion
       $scope.agentsList = data.data; 
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.agentsList));
        })      
     }]);
//*****Detail of Selected Agent ********   
   app.controller("agentsDetailCtrl",['$scope','agentDetailService' , function ($scope,agentDetailService) {
    var promise = agentDetailService.getAgentDetail();
       promise.then(function(data)
        {
        $scope.agentsDetailList = data.data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.agentsDetailList));
        })  
     }]);  
 })();//Acaba Controler
 
 /****************** SERVICE **************/(
 
 
var srv = angular.module('agentsSrv', []);

srv.service("agentsService", function($http, $q) {
 var deferred = $q.defer(); // Nuestro productor es deferred
 $http.get('../resources/agent.json').then(function(data) {  
  deferred.resolve(data);
 })
 this.getAgents = function() {
  return deferred.promise;
 }
})
**//  Method that get the data of selected agent**
srv.service("agentDetailService", function($http ,$q){
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 this.getId =  function(url){// Obtenemos la Url que nos pasara los datos
  $http.get(url).then(function(data){
   deferred.resolve(data);
  }) 
 }
 this.getAgentDetail= function(){
   return deferred.promise;
 }
})//agentDetailService
```

```html
 <div class="megamenu-container">
         
     </div>
     <div class="row">
  <div class="col-10 text-center">
             <h3 class="pt-2">Consulta de asignaciones</h3>
     </div>
  </div>
 <br/>
 <div class="card">
 
  <div class="card-header">
   <h4>Agentes</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body " ng-Controller="agentsCtrl" >
   <table class="ml-table-alt-rows">
    <thead>
     <th class="ml-table-col">No. Agente</th>
     <th class="ml-table-col">Agente</th>
     <th class="ml-table-col">Zona de promotoría</th>
     <th class="ml-table-col">Tipo de agente</th>
     <th class="ml-table-col">Seleccionar todo en página actual</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody > 
    <tr>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchAgentById" class="form-control"  >
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchAgentByName" class="form-control" >
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchAgentByZone" class="form-control" >
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchAgentByType" class="form-control" >
     </td>
    </tr>
    
     <tr dir-paginate="agent in agentsList | orderBy:'name'|filter:{id:searchAgentById,name:searchAgentByName,zone:searchAgentByZone,type:searchAgentByType}|itemsPerPage:selectPage" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" >
     <td ><label>{{agent.id}}</label></td>
     <td ><label>{{agent.name}}</label></td>
     <td ><label>{{agent.zone}}</label></td>
     <td ><label>{{agent.type}}</label></td>
     <td >
      <img src="../resources/img/inputs/detail.png" ng-Click="info(agent.id)" > 
      </fieldset>
     </td>
     
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   
 <div class="card" ng-controller="agentsDetailCtrl">
  <div class="card-header">
   <h4>Asignaciones del Agente:</h4>
   <label>Alejandra Moran Castillo,  GEID: {{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].objPolicyData.idAssign}}</label>
  </div>
   <div class="card-body">
   <div class="row">   
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>20-12-2018</label></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>Estatus:</label></div> 
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>Conducto de cobro:</label></div>
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>Retenedor(es)-Unidad de pago</label></div> <!-- "listRetainerPaymentUnit": "idRetainer":"100","nameRetainer":"RETAINER","idPaymentUnit":"109","namePaymentUnit":"PAYMEMT UNIT"  -->
     <!--****************************************************** "listFederalEntity" ************************************************ -->
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>Entidad federativa:</label></div> <!--"idFederalEntity":"MEX" "nameFederalEntity":"CDMX" -->
   </div>
   <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>{{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].objPolicyData.listStatusPolicy[0].policyStatusCode}}</label></div>
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>DxN {{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].objPolicyData.collectionType.DxN}}</label></div>
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>{{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].objPolicyData.listRetainerPaymentUnit[0].idRetainer}}</label></div>
     <div class="col-3 text-left"><label>{{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].objPolicyData.listFederalEntity[0].nameFederalEntity}}</label></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-5 text-right">
     <label>NO. DE POLIZAS EN LA SELECCIÓN:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
     <label><strong>{{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].policyDataInfo.policyNumber}}</strong></label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row"> <!-- "policyDataInfo" Objeto que incluye los datos de polizas -->
    <div class="col-5 text-right">
     <label>TAMAÑO DE POLIZAS EN LA SELECCIÓN:</label><!-- "policyNumber" (cantidad) -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
     <label><strong>{{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].policyDataInfo.sizeOfFullPolicyDataObject}} {{agentsDetailList.queryFilter[0].policyDataInfo.unitSizeFullPolicyDataObject}}</strong></label><!-- sizeOfFullPolicyDataObject(cantidad) +"unitSizeFullPolicyDataObject"(mb)-->
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in your console?

Comment: No only show for me the  JSON of first agent i was selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have some weird *deferred antipattern* where you don't use the build in promise that is returned by the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns) service, but you also trying to **reuse** the same promise for multiple http requests (Which is impossible - You can only resolve or reject a promise once).

You have the following service:

```
srv.service("agentDetailService", function($http ,$q){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    this.getId =  function(url){
        $http.get(url).then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })  
    }
    this.getAgentDetail= function(){
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

And while you always returning the same promise in `agentDetailService.getAgentDetail()`, you have a second function `agentDetailService.getId()` that will resolve that promise multiple times (If called more than once).

You can fix this issue by using the promise that was returned from the `$http` service:

```
srv.service("agentDetailService", function( $http ){
    this.getAgentDetail =  function(agent) {
        // Return the promise of the $http call directly, we don't need '$q' service at all
        return $http.get("http://localhost:9080/DAPortfolioServices-war/portfolio/v1/assign/" + agent).then(function( response ){
            // By returning 'response.data' we only expose the actual data 
            // that was returned from the server
            return response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Then in your `agentsCtrl` controller you need to resolve the promise only once - One promise per request:

```
  app.controller("agentsCtrl",['$scope','agentsService','agentDetailService' ,function ($scope,agentsService,agentDetailService) {

    //Obtains the id of Agente and inyect to url
    $scope.info = function getId (agent){
        agentDetailService.getAgentDetail(agent).then(function(data) { 
            $scope.pageNumber = 1;
            $scope.items = [10,20,30]; 
            $scope.selectPage=10; 

            // Note that I don't use 'data.data' here because the service is now responsible for that
            $scope.agentsList = data;  
        });
    }       
 }]);
```

The same deferred antipattern also apply for the second service, so you should also change it using the same method I demonstrated in the `agentDetailService`

Comment: YW. Note that I changed my answer a little bit - I moved the base url from the controller to the service to make the `agentDetailService.getAgentDetail()` method more meaningful and less generic